# Compiling and Running Ocaml Script from the Terminal

Tags: ocaml, read-eval-print-loop

I have files called `assert.ml`, `assert.mli`, `test.ml` and `test.mli` stored in a folder.  `assert` is I guess you'd call it a library file--it's something I downloaded but didn't write myself.  `test.ml` is a file containing the script

```
;; open Assert 
;; print_endline "test"
```

In the terminal I navigate to the containing folder and run

```
$ ocamlc -c assert.mli test.mli
$ ocaml assert.ml test.ml
```

Nothing happens as a result.  However, if I remove the `;; open Assert` line from the script and run

```
$ ocaml test.ml
```

then it prints.

As a note, I've had some people tell me not to write the open command as `;; open Assert` but the advice seems entirely stylistic.  I have to write it this way for the class I'm taking.

If anyone can explain to me how I ought to be compiling and running differently I'd appreciate it.  I tried following some other guides' advice in using `ocamlopt` instead but when I ran it, no executable file was produced as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ocaml` command is the REPL for OCaml. The command line looks like this:

```
ocaml [ object-files ] [ script-file ]
```

An object file is a compiled (bytecode) module, which is produced by the `ocamlc` command. These files end with `.cmo`. A script file is a file of OCaml source code, which ends with `.ml`.

Note that only one script file is allowed.

The command you say you're using has two script files and no object files. So, it's not surprising that it doesn't work. In my experiments, what `ocaml` does is run just the first of the two script files. I believe this explains what you see. One of your files produces output, and it will be run if you give it first. The other produces no output, so there is no output when that file is given first.

What you should probably be doing is producing a `.cmo` file for the `Assert` module.

That would look like this:

```
$ ocamlc -c assert.mli assert.ml test.mli
```

Then you should run `ocaml` with one object file and one script file, like this:

```
$ ocaml assert.cmo test.ml
```